# Can I do shell scripting in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix, scripting

I am a new Unix programmer. I want to practice some Unix programs but don't want to install a Unix system. I want to work only on Windows. Is there any way by which I can run shell programs on Windows?

Comment: There is [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: @cnicutar: Why don't you post it as an answer ? (It is, IMHO)

Comment: @DarkDust Because I suspect the question will be moved to superuser where there will be more competent answers.

Comment: I remember there was a site also which allowed usix scripting, it allows to run simple unix command but the commands that need admin privileges are disabled. Has anyone come across that site?

Comment: Why should it be moved. Shell scripting is programming.

Comment: search "free shell accounts unix". you can register in one of the sites and learn unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options.

- You can install cygwin for a Unix like environment.
- You can run the GNU software compiled for Windows with GnuWin32.
- Higher level scripting with Perl, Python, Ruby etc. is easy since those languages all have good Windows versions.
- There is Windows PowerShell but that will probably feel very alien to you.

Comment: i need to create files as well, will cygwin be able to do so? Are there any restrictions with cygwin as compared to proper unix?

Comment: You can create files with all the options listed above. Cygwin is not Unix so there are surely somethings that you can't do in Cygwin that you would be able to do in Unix. Please can you read the [faq] and learn about accepting answers. Not necessarily this one, but you have not accepted any yet. I guess you just haven't caught on.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a virtual machine with Ubuntu or other distribution of Linux on your Windows. VirtualBox is a good free product to do so.